# ClickOnce installer fails to install SQLLocalDb2012 because sqlcmdnutils.msi has changed since originally published

Tags: c#, clickonce, sql-server-2012-localdb

[image]

ClickOnce previously had installed SqlLocalDB2012 with no issues but now I get this error when trying to install. No issues if just updating the app from a previous version but I get this error everytime on a fresh install.

Not sure what has changed but up until recently never had an issue.I have tried changing the public keys in the product.xml file as well as clearing temporary files as some people have suggested in other posts. Neither worked for me.

> "Setup has detected that the file
>   'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD7502.tmp\SqlLocaDB2012\x64\sqlcmdnutils.msi'
>   has changed since it was initially published."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  After also trying the other remedies proposed, I decided to add the prerequisite software into my application, rather than downloading from the component vendor's website.  Microsoft's guidance on how to do this is here:

```html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-include-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN
```

.
Note that (1) for Windows10, you will find the SqlLocalDB packages folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages.  (2) For SqlLocalDB, you need to include both x64 (Windows 64 bit) and x86 (Windows 32 bit) versions, and will need to create x64 and x86 folders within your ClickOnce Bootstrap\Packages\SqlLocalDB2012 folder to hold the installation files. (3) You cannot have some prerequisites loaded from an external source and some from the application - it's all or nothing.  So you may need to repeat the exercise for other prerequisites, e.g. .Net.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing the same. It was the only thing that worked as a permanent fix. Sorry for not posting my answer!